# Retrieve first portion from the path name [/sample/v1]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a get request in node js. I want the base url path as http://localhost:80/sample and different requests as /v1, /v2.
So, the concatenated url will be http://localhost:80/sample/v1?querystring=10.

How can I segeregate the base path as http://localhost:80/sample, since when I try to get the pathname, I am getting /sample/v1?

Please help me with node js not using express.

**UPDATE:**

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
}
```

where the request.url is localhost:80/sample/v1?q=10.

I need to validate if its either "v1" or "v2" by fethcing in the url instead of validating with the entire pathname like pathname.indexOf('v1') process something.

Comment: Can you paste example, that you've tried?

Comment: @vanadium23, function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;} where the request.url is  http://localhost:80/sample/v1?q=10. I need to validate if its either "v1" or "v2" by fethcing in the url  instead of validating  with the entire pathname like pathname.indexOf('v1') process something. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Seeing as it's a URL path, couldn't you just split the string on `'/'` and get the first entry? `url.parse(request.url).pathname.split('/')[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't know why do you prefer scheme /{method}/{api_version}, because companies are prefer reversed to your order. (E.g. [twitter console](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console)).

**Example #1**, if your method doesn't contain additional slashes:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname.split('/');
    var version = pathName[2]; // v1 or v2
    var methodName = pathName[1]; // sample
}
```

**Example #2**, if you method will contain additional /, e.g. `/user/19292/v1`:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var match = pathName.match(/\/v\d+$/);
    if(match != null) {
        var version = match[0]; //v1 or v2
        var methodName = pathName.replace(/\/v\d+$/, ''); // /user/19229
    } else {
        // No version was provided
    }
}
```